# What is real difference between old Intel Xeon E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz and new Intel Xeon Gold 5218 @ 2.30GHz

Tags: ibm, intel, xeon, bare-metal

We are hosting file processing SAAS on `Intel Xeon E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz` and recently the `Intel Xeon Gold 5218 @ 2.30GHz (Cascade Lake/Gold)` is introduced in our data center. While comparing them at https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/Intel-Xeon-E5-2690-v3-vs-Intel-Xeon-Gold-5218/2364vs3536 the Intel Xeon Gold 5218 seems faster and it cost **cheaper** in our data center. Also has more cores `12 vs 16`.

I am not an expert in hardware, maybe someone could explain why bigger and faster cost less? What is the difference between `E5` and `Gold` Intel CPU versions?

Comment: The vendor, Intel, publishes the exact specs of all their CPU’s on https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark.html - prices differ on release date, target market and many other factors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Xeon E5-2690 v3` is an old Haswell-based Xeon, with less core but more cache. It is from an era when Intel faced basically no competition on the server CPU side, and it was priced according.

The `Xeon Gold 5218` is a Cascade Lake (Skylake refresh) CPU. It has a significantly better IPC (5-10%) and higher frequency, resulting in better performance. However, it is priced much better due to AMD Epyc competition.

Between the two CPUs I would select the `Xeon Gold 5218` even at same price. As it is cheaper, it is even a better deal.